# How to handle validate in remix

Tags: shopify, remix.run

So I have an POST API in remix.

How can I validate these field in a middleware? Is there any lib that support this or do I have to write checking in every file for every field in object.

```
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";

export const action = async ({params, request}) => {

    let raw_data = await request.text();
    let body = JSON.parse(raw_data)

    const customerProfile = JSON.stringify({
        session_id: body?.session_id,
        first_name: body?.first_name,
        last_name: body?.last_name,
        phone: body?.phone,
        email: body?.email,
    })
    // Do something here

    return json(
        { ...result },
        {
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"
            },
        }
    );
}
```

The request is from another server not in same server.

Comment: Have you looked at validation libraries like `zod` or `yup`?